# MS Access. Grouping records by date

Tags: ms-access-2013

Using MS Access. I'm trying to write a report, grouped by date into weeks (Mon thru Sunday) and give a total of all transactions during the week.

There are only two tables.

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT tblBuyer.BuyerTradeDate, [booksold]-[bookpaid]-[booktradefee] AS Outcome
FROM tblSale INNER JOIN tblBuyer ON tblSale.BuyerID = tblBuyer.buyerID;
```

My query returns two columns, BuyerTradeDate and Outcome.

The image below shows some test data.

[Sample output from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi6Vt.png)

I need the report to display:

[Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9YfK.png)

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Post table structure

Comment: BuyerTradeDate is date field.  Booksold, bookpaid, and booktrademefee are all currency fields.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to set up the date ranges in your report, but I suggest go have a read up on `having`, `group by`, `sum`, and other aggregate clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've come up with that provides the solution I need.

In the report I've added a BuyerTradeDate header with a txt box containing:

```
="Week Number: " & Format$([BuyerTradeDate],"ww",0,0)
```

I've added a BuyerTradeDate Footer with a txt box containing:

```
="Summary for week beginning: " & " " & [BuyerTradeDate] & " (" & Count(*) & " " & IIf(Count(*)=1,"Trade","Trades") & ")"
```

The report looks like this:

[Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAGTd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a field in your source query or in your report having this expression as control source:

```
=Weekday([BuyerTradeDate],2)
```

Then group on this in your report.

To have the first and the last date of the week, use these functions:

```
Public Function DateWeekFirst( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal lngFirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
  As Date

' Returns the first date of the week of datDate.
' lngFirstDayOfWeek defines the first weekday of the week.
' 2000-09-07. Cactus Data ApS.
' 2003-05-01. System settings used as default.
' 2012-10-44. Data type of lngFirstDayOfWeek changed to VbDayOfWeek.

  DateWeekFirst = DateAdd("d", vbSunday - Weekday(datDate, lngFirstDayOfWeek), datDate)

End Function

Public Function DateWeekLast( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal lngFirstDayOfWeek As Long = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
  As Date

' Returns the last date of the week of datDate.
' lngFirstDayOfWeek defines the first weekday of the week.
' 2000-09-07. Cactus Data ApS.
' 2003-05-01. System settings used as default.
' 2012-10-44. Data type of lngFirstDayOfWeek changed to VbDayOfWeek.

  DateWeekLast = DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(datDate, lngFirstDayOfWeek), datDate)

End Function
```

Comment: He wants the week, so instead of `Weekday` you'll need `DatePart("ww", [BuyerTradeDate], 2)`.

Comment: No, that will just complicate matters. `Weekday` does return the weekday number.

Comment: I've added a header to the report. i.e. the report has BuyerTradeDate header, with txtbox containing =Format$([BuyerTradeDate],"ww",0,0).

It does give me what I want, although ideally instead of the week number, I would prefer to see a date range.

I.e. where it displays week number "3", it would be better to display 12 January 15 - 18 January 15.

Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Thanks for your help guys - much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, functions for this have been included in my answer.